# Allowing third party users to upload files into your AWS S3 fs

Tags: file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a pretty tough problem here: I need to allow the users of my site to upload very large files to their accounts and I want to store these files on a AWS S3 filesystem. I can't just write a web service to receive these and save them in the S3 fs, because all kinds of things can go wrong during the upload and I need a sophisticated uploader client. The kind of client that Amazon provides to upload files into S3, but of course I can't give my users direct access to that. I'd seriously appreciate any ideas for this!

Thank you

Comment: take a look at [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com). it allows uploading huge files and copying them to your s3 bucket without exposing it.

Answer (score 19):

Best practice would be to let your client application to upload directly to S3, not flowing through your own web infrastructure.  This would leverage ether massive parallel nature of S3 and off-load your web infrastructure.  Offloading your infrastructure will allow to use less instances or smaller instances to serve the same amount of traffic.  Hence a lower infrastructure cost for you.

You would need to write an S3 IAM Policy that would limit access for each of your user to their own "directory" (aka key prefix) on S3

Have a look at this blog post : http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke

If your application is a web app, you can even let your customers' browsers upload directly to S3.  See how to implement this securely at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html

Just a last note about your question : S3 is not a file system, S3 is an object store.  Read more about the differences between object storage and file system at http://www.infoworld.com/article/2614094/data-center/what-is-object-storage-.html

Answer (score 1):

first you will need to create users on your AWS account, next you assign roles to these users, given them access to AWS services such as s3. Then you create Identity access for theses roles and relax yourself. AWS does the rest. you dont need to bother about cloudfront APIs. if you do what is needed as outlined here, problem would be solved.