# Integrating S3 with custom user management

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, loopbackjs

We are building a custom application (using [LoopBack](http://loopback.io/)) that will need to store many large files coming from multiple users, so naturally we're looking at S3. We've done something similar before, with clients uploading files to the server which then processes and uploads them to S3 under one AWS account, but for this new app, we're looking to allow the clients (using a custom iOS app) to use the iOS S3 SDK to upload directly to their own bucket or folder. User accounts will be created on the server.

Is there any way to handle S3 authentication/authorization using custom code? For example, could the iOS client request a temporary token allowing them to upload to a specific S3 bucket or folder? Or would we need to create unique IAM users for each user in our system?

Is that a terrible idea? It sounds like a terrible idea. :)

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614667/allowing-third-party-users-to-upload-files-into-your-aws-s3-fs) but there was no conclusive answer.

**Update**: I found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) article on Temporary Security Credentials that looks very promising. It also suggests using Cognito, which I've never used, if building a mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito is the way to go. You should definetly not create IAM users for this. IAM is for managing access to the aws services programatically or from the console. Moreover you would need to hardcode the IAM access keys in the ios app, which is not a best practice.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_cognito.html

Comment: This is the approach we're going with. I've got it 99% working already (just sorting out the role's policy file for S3 access.)

Answer (score 1):

If users of your application are already authenticated, you could generate a pre-signed S3 url on your backend using your credentials. This URL can then be returned to the application and used to upload a file.

It would circumvent having to create individual IAM users/permissions and/or managing bucket policies.

Check out the docs on it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

Comment: This is great to know, we actually will be using pre-signed URLs elsewhere in the app. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how relevant to your situation.

You can create a role that allows upload to s3 and use SAML web-based identity to authenticate and allow privileges to assume the role and get temp credentials and token.

This will keep very limited time authenticated to S3 upload. ie until the temp credentials expire.