# Which is the best AWS service (Elastic Beanstalk/ECS/EC2) to proxy memory heavy POST requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, amazon-ec2, proxy

## What I'm trying to achieve

[image]

The proxy service receives `multipart/form-data POST requests` containing **large files**. It then uploads the files to S3 and performs multiple API calls. This is a multi-tenant SaaS that must withstand high throughput and concurrency, with minimal latency. All this is invisible to the user who just makes a single call and receives response. The **proxy does not do any computational tasks**.

**Platform to be used used**: Golang / NodeJS

### Options I've considered

1. **Elastic beanstalk**: The one I'm familiar with and currently considering.
2. **Elastic container service(ECS)**: What benefits can it bring compared to option 1? Consider both EC2 and Fargate model.
3. **EC2**: Is the task achievable with linux shell scripts and how does it compare with other options?
4. **API gateway**: Not an option due to 10MB limit. Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58993864/how-can-i-bypass-the-10mb-limit-of-aws-api-gateway-and-post-large-files-to-aws-l) before posting.
5. Other services, if any

### Factors to consider

1. **Scaling**: Consider thousands of users uploading GBs of files simultaneously. Latency should be minimal.
2. **Costs**
3. **Complexity**:
4. **Performance**: Is container / VM management worth the performance boost, if any?
5. **Redundancy**: Keep redundant servers while keeping complexity minimal.

Comment: So I guess you are not in control of the client side? If you are you should use s3 signed URLS to upload to s3 directly. Explained in the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614667/allowing-third-party-users-to-upload-files-into-your-aws-s3-fs

Comment: Hi! I know about signed URLs, but for this case I want the proxy to take up the burden. The **client side sends one request only**. For a pure Lambda + S3 signed bucket solution, multiple API calls will be needed. This was explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58996271/7721443

Comment: Where does that one request only limitation come from? The 10MB limit is not without a reason. How big are your files and why do you insist on sending them in one request?

Comment: Consider it as a prototype, the calls made by proxy could be to something else as well. I just wanted a comparison of the proxying performance of different services, this going in another direction.

Comment: I don't think proxying is the term for what you need here. You are saying that it does not do any computational task yet you expect it to put objects to s3 and forward the request to another service?